# Suggest some python automation Testing Frameworks

Tags: automated-testing

Suggest some python automation Testing Frameworks that can be used in my projects where we interact with BigData applications like

- HDFS.
- Base
- Kafka
- Flume and so on..

Comment: Kafka provides python consumer and producers clients in Python. HDFS and other probably as well. Why do you need a framework? Why individual libraries are not enough?

Comment: Thanks dzieciou... I agree with you that we have individual libraries. But as a team here we need to follow some set of protocols, and for easy reporting tips and so on.. so i thought if we go with a framework it would be easy and satisfies many more basic guidelines that a org needs.. What do you say???

Comment: @Now we're talking about actual requirements :-) `pytesy`, `unittest` are Python test runners that generate also reports. And they can be integrated with other python libraries easily. What kind of protocols do you mean? You can update your question with them, so they define requirements for the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored [Golem - Test Automation Framework](https://github.com/golemhq/golem)

**Intro**

Golem is a complete test automation tool for web browser testing. It creates powerful, robust and maintainable test suites, it's easy to learn even without a lot of programming knowledge. It is based on Selenium Webdriver and it can be extended using Python.

**It can:**

Use the Page Object pattern
Write tests with multi data sets (data-driven)
Run tests in parallel.
Test APIs
Run tests remotely (Selenium Grid or a cloud testing provider)
It can be executed from Jenkins or any other CI tool

**It has:**

A complete GUI module (a web application) to write and execute tests
A reporting engine and a web reports module
An interactive console